# get latest string value of groupBy in python

Tags: python, string, datetime, group-by

I want to get the latest (by 'date') value of a key from a df in python.
this is my data frame:

```
key     date      value
1    10/02/2010    'a'
1    13/02/2010    'c' 
1    10/02/2010    'a'   
1    11/02/2010    'b' 
3    15/12/2013    'r'   
3    04/03/2011    'g'   
3    04/03/2012    'a'   
4    11/12/2018    'b'
```

sample output:

```
key     date      value
1    13/02/2010    'c'   
3    15/12/2013    'r'   
4    11/12/2018    'b'
```

*****I know I can sort the data frame by dates and get the first row but I prefers not to use sort.

what can I do?

Comment: Can you give sample output as well? What do you mean by latest key value?

Comment: @J...S I have added a sample output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below, it does by `'date'` as you wanted, and gets in expected order, and outputs expected result:

```
print(df[df.groupby('key')['date'].transform(max) == df['date']])
```

Comment: It says it returns last row of each group so I will have to sort by date and like I said I wont to avoid that.

Comment: where the function use the date col?

Comment: @anat What ya mean?

Comment: I cant use sort for the dates, how would I know the value is right?

Comment: @anat Because i did `keep='last'` so the value is always gonna be right.

Comment: @anat Not the index, the dataframe.

Comment: without giving the function a specific date column to consider?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes `key` is the index, as it seems:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.groupby('key').date.apply(lambda x: x.max())
```

Comment: like I mention - I dont want to sort and get last.

Comment: `df.duplicated` is not sorting, it selects the last sample for each unique index. Why is this not good to solve the problem?

Comment: Updated the solution. Does this solev your problem now?

Comment: no, again - I dont want to sort the data, the latest row index is not the latest date.

Comment: I really don't know what you want then with what you've explained. Do you want the last item in each group (grouping by index), or the maximum date? Or what is it?

Comment: I want to value from col 'value' that goes with the maximum date.

Comment: So to groupby key and get maximum date?

Comment: Okay, I'd appreciate that you don't downvote, given that I've made an effort to give an answer